# pxd not found when building cython into cpp

Tags: python, cython

I have a directory structure like this:

```
project/lib/src/a.pyx 
project/lib/src/<some other files>
project/helpers/cython/b.pyx
project/helpers/cython/b.pxd
project/helpers/cython/setup.py
project/helpers/cython/__init__.py
```

`project/helpers/cython/setup.py` looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("helpers/cython/b.pyx"),
)
```

in `a.pyx`, I have the following lines:

```
import helpers.cython.b as utils
cimport helpers.cython.b as utils_c
```

when, in `project/lib/`, I run
`cython src/*.pyx srsc/*.pxd -a --cplus`, I get the error message

```
import helpers.cython.b as utils
cimport helpers.cython.b as utils_c
       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

a.pyx:29:8: 'helpers/cython/b.pxd' not found
```

when I do not have the `cimport` line, cython has no problem finding the correct directory.

Thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong? I've tried to follow examples given in the docs in setting this up, but without success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Try letting cython have access to your `project` directory through `include_dirs`, like so:

`cython src/*.pyx srs/*.pxd -a --cplus --include-dir ../`